# All PHP sessions deleted from Apache

Tags: php, centos6, apache2

Yesterday, we faced a strange issue. We have our application in PHP hosted on an Apache server. Suddenly, all our users were logged out from the application. In apache log we didn’t find any log entries as well for 5-10 minutes. We are not sure how all PHP sessions are deleted. Is It possible?

Our monitoring says disk space utilisation was above 90% at that time.

Comment: This can happen for numerous reasons, but some sort of hint should be in your log files. Either the php, apache or kernel/system logs. Are you sure the disk space did not reach 100% at some point? That would explain the downtime. Would not explain the automatic deletion of sessions, though.

Comment: By default, with [`session.save_handler = "files"`](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-handler) and  [`session.save_path = ""`](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path)  PHP sessions are stored as files in your temp space, maybe an admin cleaned that to free up some space

Comment: Look at the php.ini and give us session handler info please.